# Not all dividers and texts in jetpack compose row get displayed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to build this layout:

[image: desired layout]

I tried with this code (and some variations with weights):

```
@Composable
fun TodayRow(amount: String) {

Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(colorResource(id = R.color.bg_creamy))
        .height(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.list_item_height_normal))
) {
    Divider(
        color = colorResource(id = R.color.dark_mode_black_2),
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(14.dp)
    )
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.today),
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
        color = colorResource(id = R.color.dark_mode_black_2),
        fontSize = 13.sp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 2.dp, end = 2.dp)

    )
    Divider(
        color = colorResource(id = R.color.dark_mode_black_2),
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(end = 2.dp)

    )
    Text(
        text = amount,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
        color = colorResource(id = R.color.dark_mode_black_2),
        fontSize = 13.sp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(end = 2.dp)

    )
    Divider(
        color = colorResource(id = R.color.dark_mode_black_2),
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(14.dp)
    )
}
```

}

What i get is this (missing last text and divider):
[image: result layout]

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are using end padding on the second divider. It is extending until there is only two dp from the edge of the screen. Try weights instead

Comment: The other text seems to have been squished to zero width since it also has to be 2dps from the edge, but it can't sit on top of the divider.

Comment: Removed end padding from second divider and adding Modifier.weight(1f) to it fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Actually this could have been noticed, through your screenshot, by looking at the right edge of the screen, where there's a gap between the screen and the line, and then looking at the left edge where the line intersects the edge